# share link of website on whatsapp with image tag also

Tags: html, asp.net, plugins, whatsapp

How can we include an image in our website to display in WhatsApp when we share a link like this?

Code

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="####"></script>  // plugin from
```

> **www.addthis.com**

```
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an image for most of social sharing website, you will need to add some metadata in the head tag of your website

The metatag you are looking for specifically is "og:image". Here is an example.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
```

Where the content field would point to the image you want. This tag will be used when you share your website on a lot of social media (WhatsApp, Facebook, LinkedIn...)

Note that for Twitter the tag is "twitter:image:src"

For more info you can look at this https://ogp.me/